# Using GREP to replace all but matched string

Tags: regex, grep, textwrangler

I'm using TextWrangler to get specific information from an XML. I need to find a list of file names that are present and print out only those file names.

An example of the code is below:

```
<file id="file_1045280">
    <name>SKY_A026C032_150707_R4RO.mov</name>
    <pathurl>file://localhost/M:/FPL_MEDIA/04_MEZZANINE/SKY/SKY-EP03/SKY-0312_20150707_AA_A026/SKY_A026C032_150707_R4RO.mov</pathurl>
    <duration>1796</duration>
    <timecode>
        <rate>
            <ntsc>false</ntsc>
            <timebase>25</timebase>
        </rate>
        <frame>0</frame>
        <displayformat>NDF</displayformat>
    </timecode>
    <media>
        <video>
            <duration>1796</duration>
            <samplecharacteristics>
                <width>1920</width>
                <height>1080</height>
            </samplecharacteristics>
        </video>
    </media>
</file>
                            <sourcetrack>
                                <mediatype>video</mediatype>
                            </sourcetrack>
                            <link>
                                <linkclipref>clipItem_1045280</linkclipref>
                                <mediatype>video</mediatype>
                                <trackindex>1</trackindex>
                            </link>
                        </clipitem>
                        <enabled>TRUE</enabled>
                        <locked>FALSE</locked>
                    </track>
                </video>
            </media>
        </clip>
        <clip id="clip_1045282">
            <name>SKY_A026C018_150707_R4RO</name>
            <duration>958</duration>
            <rate>
                <ntsc>false</ntsc>
                <timebase>25</timebase>
            </rate>
            <in>-1</in>
            <out>-1</out>
            <masterclipid>clip_1045282</masterclipid>
            <ismasterclip>TRUE</ismasterclip>
            <media>
                <video>
                    <track>
                        <clipitem id="clipitem_1045282">
                            <name>SKY_A026C018_150707_R4RO</name>
                            <duration>958</duration>
                            <masterclipid>clip_1045282</masterclipid>
                            <rate>
                                <ntsc>false</ntsc>
                                <timebase>25</timebase>
                            </rate>
                            <in>0</in>
                            <out>958</out>
                            <start>0</start>
                            <end>958</end>
<file id="file_1045282">
    <name>SKY_A026C018_150707_R4RO.mov</name>
    <pathurl>file://localhost/M:/FPL_MEDIA/04_MEZZANINE/SKY/SKY-EP03/SKY-0312_20150707_AA_A026/SKY_A026C018_150707_R4RO.mov</pathurl>
    <duration>958</duration>
    <timecode>
        <rate>
            <ntsc>false</ntsc>
            <timebase>25</timebase>
        </rate>
        <frame>0</frame>
        <displayformat>NDF</displayformat>
    </timecode>
    <media>
        <video>
            <duration>958</duration>
            <samplecharacteristics>
                <width>1920</width>
                <height>1080</height>
            </samplecharacteristics>
        </video>
    </media>
</file>
                            <sourcetrack>
                                <mediatype>video</mediatype>
                            </sourcetrack>
                            <link>
                                <linkclipref>clipItem_1045282</linkclipref>
                                <mediatype>video</mediatype>
                                <trackindex>1</trackindex>
                            </link>
                        </clipitem>
                        <enabled>TRUE</enabled>
                        <locked>FALSE</locked>
                    </track>
                </video>
            </media>
        </clip>
        <clip id="clip_1045283">
            <name>SKY_A026C033_150707_R4RO</name>
            <duration>1202</duration>
            <rate>
                <ntsc>false</ntsc>
                <timebase>25</timebase>
            </rate>
            <in>-1</in>
            <out>-1</out>
            <masterclipid>clip_1045283</masterclipid>
            <ismasterclip>TRUE</ismasterclip>
            <media>
                <video>
                    <track>
                        <clipitem id="clipitem_1045283">
                            <name>SKY_A026C033_150707_R4RO</name>
                            <duration>1202</duration>
                            <masterclipid>clip_1045283</masterclipid>
                            <rate>
                                <ntsc>false</ntsc>
                                <timebase>25</timebase>
                            </rate>
                            <in>0</in>
                            <out>1202</out>
                            <start>0</start>
                            <end>1202</end>
```

At the moment, I am using the following Grep:

```
.*?(\<name\>)(.*)(.mov).*
```

This manages to find the strings that I need. However, I need to replace all of the remaining text with nothing i.e. so I'm left with a list of file names.

Can anyone advise how I may go about this?

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Comment: Do you need the output to be only `<name>SKY_A026C032_150707_R4RO.mov</name><name>SKY_A026C018_150707_R4RO.mov</name>` ?

Comment: In an ideal solution, I would want the output to be SKY_A026C032_150707_R4RO.mov only, minus the <name> and </name> tags, but your solution would suffice as I could just run a second Grep.

Comment: do you have perl installed ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It would need to be done in TextWrangler as it needs to be run on a locked-down XSAN environment and that is the only software available on our SOE.

Comment: I'm sorry but grep mislead me, I cannot help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Using TextWrangler, a quick way had been to first use -> **Text** -> **Process Lines Containing...** to search for `<name>.+\.mov</name>` with **Grep** and **Copy to new document** checked.
The resulting file could be cleaned up searching for (something along) `^\s*<name>(.+\.mov)</name>\s*$` and replacing with `\1` with **Grep** checked.

Answer (score -1):

How about this.  THere's a bit of overlap, but it means

```
"match everything as if it's a single line that 
[comes after </name> and before <name>], or 
[is between the beginning and <name>] or 
[is the <name> or </name> tags itself].

(?ms)(?<=<\/name>)(.*?)(?=<name>)|(^.*?<name>)|(<.?name>)

https://regex101.com/r/vV4xZ6/2
```

Comment: That's very close @ergonaut, thank you. 

Would there be a way to only list the instances of the file name that end in .mov? So the instance of the file name after the <file id> tag, but not the <clip id> tag?

That way, the actual file name is only listed once per file.

Comment: it's quite complex, the best solution would be to use an actual parser.

Comment: I"m afraid I don't know what that means? 

Essentially, I just want to find the results of that Grep you've done that ends in .mov. 

I have tried modifying your expression to reflect that, but it always finds anything contained between the <name></name> tags. 

Is there any way to modify it so that it's lookahead/behind means that the string between the <name></tags> has to end in .mov to remain after the replace?

Comment: Or, finding the string after the final forward slash before </pathurl> e.g. /SKY_A026C032_150707_R4RO.mov</pathurl> would give the same result?

Comment: Sorry I don't have an answer for you.  However my answer is the negative case of what you had originally.  It might be easier to take the positive case, and extract those in a separate file.